# Push up animation in android is not working

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a tab widget and `ListView` under that.
I want to move the tab and `ListView` simultaneously upside with my finger movement.
I used `onTouchListener` for the `ListView` to catch the events.
But it's not working.

I want this animation like in Chrome browser.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

With this library you can do it, and much more effects and animations for listviews:
[ObservableScrollView](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView)

New tutorial for your case: [Tutorial how to hide and show Toolbar and footer](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling%28part1%29/)

Comment: I have alreday tried this library. I am not able to get how to use the library. My problem is I have tabs on top and down and list [I made using fragment] in between. When i scroll up, top tab should move up and down top to bottom with list and so forth hide. And if i scroll down, top tab and down tab should re-appear with the list movement. listView.setOnTouchListener: suppose I scroll up. I get Y using event.getRawY() function. but Y value is not correct. It causes flickering.If I use threshold value to avoid flickering, tabs hiding/showing is not happening with list movement.

Comment: Please help it's very urgent. I saw different library but didnot get how to use them.

Comment: Can anyone give a sample example

Comment: Sorry I have not had much time the last few days. the library that I showed you do not work for what you want. There are several examples that explain how to do something similar to what you want.
In this link https://github.com/lawloretienne/QuickReturn there something similar but you'll have to use the idea and adapt it to your code, or look for something else online, there will be more examples. Search for Fixed header and footer fixed

Comment: I have tried it. But no success. Can i add my tabhost to the ListView as header?

Comment: This is my last shot, i implemented this and working fine, you should adapt this code. This show how to hide and show toolbar and footer when scroll and how to implement tabs. https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling%28part1%29/

Comment: Can anybody explain how font change in phone is applied to the application in android?